# How To Access access Case class field Value from String name of the field

Tags: scala, case-class

How should I extract the value of a field of a case class from a given String value representing the field.

For example:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
val a = Person("test",10)
```

Now here given a string `name`  or `age` i want to extract the value from variable `a`. How do i do this? I know this can be done using reflection but I am not exactly sure how?

Comment: And i want to be able to extract the value safely. Meaning that if the field is not there i should get None or something.

Comment: In what use case might a `Person` not be expected to have a `name` or `age`?

Comment: In the use case where the system does not have complete information.

Answer (score 9):

What you're looking for can be achieve using Shapeless lenses. This will also put the constraint that a field actually exists on a case class at compile time rather than run time:

```
import shapeless._

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val nameLens = lens[Person] >> 'name
val p = Person("myName", 25)

nameLens.get(p)
```

Yields:

```
res0: String = myName
```

If you try to extract a non existing field, you get a *compile time* error, which is a much stronger guarantee:

```
import shapeless._

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val nonExistingLens = lens[Person] >> 'bla
val p = Person("myName", 25)

nonExistingLens.get(p)
```

Compiler yells:

```
Error:(5, 44) could not find implicit value for parameter mkLens: shapeless.MkFieldLens[Person,Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("bla")]]
val nonExistingLens = lens[Person] >> 'bla
```

Comment: Could we use `String` instead of `Symbol` like `'bla` ?

Comment: @Thomas Hi, did you ever find out a way to use a String variable instead of a Symbol like 'bla

Comment: @pleasehalp You can't just use any arbitrary String variable since the Symbol needs to be known at compile time.

Comment: Aah, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

don't know exactly what you had in mind, but a `match` statement would do, it is not very generic or extensible with regards changes to the `Person` case class, but it does meet your basic requirements of not using reflection:

```
scala> val a = Person("test",10)
a: Person = Person(test,10)

scala> def extract(p: Person, fieldName: String) = {
     |   fieldName match {
     |     case "name" => p.name
     |     case "age" => p.age
     |   }
     | }
extract: (p: Person, fieldName: String)Any

scala> extract(a, "name")
res1: Any = test

scala> extract(a, "age")
res2: Any = 10

scala> extract(a, "name####")
scala.MatchError: name#### (of class java.lang.String)
  at .extract(<console>:14)
  ... 32 elided
```

---

**UPDATE as per comment:**

```
scala> case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
defined class Person

scala> val a = Person("test",10)
a: Person = Person(test,10)


scala> def extract(p: Person, fieldName: String) = {
     |   fieldName match {
     |     case "name" => Some(p.name)
     |     case "age" => Some(p.age)
     |     case _ => None
     |   }
     | }
extract: (p: Person, fieldName: String)Option[Any]

scala> extract(a, "name")
res4: Option[Any] = Some(test)

scala> extract(a, "age")
res5: Option[Any] = Some(10)

scala> extract(a, "name####")
res6: Option[Any] = None

scala>
```

Comment: Ya but then i need to write a wrapper. I want to achieve this at runtime without manually writing a wrapper function.

Comment: then perhaps checkout shapeless:
[shapeless lenses](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#boilerplate-free-lenses-for-arbitrary-case-classes)

Answer (score 0):

I think it can do by convert case class to Map, then get field by name

```
def ccToMap(cc: AnyRef) =
  (Map[String, Any]() /: cc.getClass.getDeclaredFields) {
     (a, f) =>
     f.setAccessible(true)
     a + (f.getName -> f.get(cc))
}
```

Usage

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val column = Person("me", 16)
println(ccToMap(column))
val name = ccToMap(column)["name"]
```