# accessing a field of scala case class dynamically

Tags: scala, apache-spark, case-class

below is a sample case class:

```
case class sample(countPerResponse: Map[String,Long], countPerId: Map[String,Long]... many more maps)
```

I wish to perform the same calculations over the maps in the object of this case class and was thinking of creating a single method to do so.
Is there any way to do this:

```
sampleObject.get("dynamic string having value as one of my fields").foreach(keyvaluepair => {bla bla calculations})
```

Comment: Can you do this? Yes. Should you do this? Probably no. For example, if you want to do such operations, why you pack your data in such way (that giant case class) to make it hard?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547860/how-to-access-access-case-class-field-value-from-string-name-of-the-field

Comment: I am parsing some json data and need to convert it to an object. hence the 4-5 maps i am using. also, thanks for pointing to the link! :)

Comment: If you are parsing json into maps anyway, why bother with the case class at top level? Just make that a map too ...

Comment: Hi Dima, I have other attributes too. not just maps in the json string. Case class seemed the best idea for my problem statement